# Datatables jquery - default pagination, ordering doesn't work

Tags: php, jquery, pagination, datatables

I load a serverside processing, and data loads, but I cant paginate, ordering, or use search tab.

My code is like this:

> HTML code

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <title>admin</title>
      <!-- Place favicon.ico and apple-touch-icon.png in the root directory -->
      <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.4/css/bootstrap.min.css">



    <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles/dataTables.bootstrap.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles/main.css">


</head>

<body>


<nav class="navbar navbar-default navbar-fixed-top">
  <div class="container-fluid">
    <!-- Brand and toggle get grouped for better mobile display -->
    <div class="navbar-header">
      <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#bs-example-navbar-collapse-1">
        <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
      </button>
      <a class="navbar-brand" href="#"> <img src="images/logo-mini.png" alt="logo intothemarketing" class="img-responsive" height="30px" width="30px" /></a>
    </div>

    <!-- Collect the nav links, forms, and other content for toggling -->
    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="bs-example-navbar-collapse-1">
      <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
        <li class="active"><a href="#">Articulos</a></li>
        <li class="dropdown">
         <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" role="button" aria-expanded="false">Listados <span class="caret"></span></a>
          <ul class="dropdown-menu" role="menu">
            <li><a href="#">Clientes</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Medios Digitales</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Editores</a></li>
          </ul>
        </li>
        <li><a href="#">Historico</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Facturas</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Registro</a></li>
      </ul>

      <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
        <li><a href="logout.php">Logout</a></li>
      </ul>

    </div><!-- /.navbar-collapse -->
  </div><!-- /.container-fluid -->
</nav>

   <div class="container-fluid">

        <div id="tabla" class="row">
            <div class="col-md-12">
                <table id="miTabla" class="table stripe">
                <!--cabecera de la pagina, titulo e icono-->

        <div id="edicionok" class="alert alert-success" role="alert">Edicion correta!</div>
    <div id="edicionerr" class="alert alert-danger" role="alert">Edicion erronea!</div>

                <!--boton añadir doctor-->
                <button id="creaDoc" type="button" class="btn btn-success navbar-btn">Añadir doctor</button>
                 <!--boton añadir doctor-->

                <!--tabla-->
                    <thead>
                         <th>ID Contenido</th>
                        <th>Contenido</th>
                        <th>Fecha Inicio</th>
                        <th>Fecha Modificación</th>
                        <th>Descripción</th>
                        <th>Precio</th>
                        <th>Cliente</th>
                        <th>Medio</th>
                        <th>Editor</th>
                        <th>Editar</th>
                    </thead>
                    <tbody>
                    </tbody>
                    <tfoot>
                    <th>ID Contenido</th>
                         <th>Contenido</th>
                        <th>Fecha Inicio</th>
                        <th>Fecha Modificación</th>
                        <th>Descripción</th>
                        <th>Precio</th>
                        <th>Cliente</th>
                        <th>Medio</th>
                        <th>Editor</th>
                        <th>Editar</th>
                    </tfoot>
                </table>

            </div>


        </div>





    <script src="scripts/jquery.js"></script>
    <script src="../bower_components/bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap.js"></script>
    <script src="../bower_components/bootstrap.growl/bootstrap-growl.js"></script>
    <script src="../bower_components/jquery-validate/dist/jquery.validate.js"></script>    
    <script src="scripts/jquery.dataTables.js"></script>
    <script src="scripts/dataTables.bootstrap.js"></script>
     <script src="scripts/modal.js"></script>

    <script src="scripts/main.js"></script> 
</body>
</html>
```

> Main.js

```
    'use strict';

var IdContenido;

$(document).ready(function() {

  var miTabla = $('#miTabla').DataTable({
           'processing': true,
           'serverSide': true,
           'ajax': 'php/cargar-publi.php',
           'language': {
               'sProcessing': 'Procesando...',
               'sLengthMenu': 'Mostrar _MENU_ registros',
               'sZeroRecords': 'No se encontraron resultados',
               'sEmptyTable': 'Ningún dato disponible en esta tabla',
               'sInfo': 'Mostrando registros del _START_ al _END_ de un total de _TOTAL_ registros',
               'sInfoEmpty': 'Mostrando registros del 0 al 0 de un total de 0 registros',
               'sInfoFiltered': '(filtrado de un total de _MAX_ registros)',
               'sInfoPostFix': '',
               'sSearch': 'Buscar:',
               'sUrl': '',
               'sInfoThousands': ',',
               'sLoadingRecords': 'Cargando...',
               'oPaginate': {
                   'sFirst': 'Primero',
                   'sLast': 'Último',
                   'sNext': 'Siguiente',
                   'sPrevious': 'Anterior'
               },
               'oAria': {
                   'sSortAscending': ': Activar para ordenar la columna de manera ascendente',
                   'sSortDescending': ': Activar para ordenar la columna de manera descendente'
               }
           },
           'columns': [
           {
               'data': 'IdContenido'
           }, {
               'data': 'contenido'
           },{
               'data': 'fecha_inicio'
           },{
               'data': 'fecha_modificacion'
           },{
               'data': 'descripcion'
           },{
               'data': 'precio'
           },{
               'data': 'cliente'
           },{
               'data': 'medio'
           }, {
               'data': 'editor',
                'render': function(data) {
                   return '<li>' + data + '</li><br>';
               }
           },  {
               'data': 'IdContenido',
               /*añadimos las clases editarbtn y borrarbtn para procesar los eventos click de los botones. No lo hacemos mediante id ya que habrá más de un
               botón de edición o borrado*/
               'render': function(data) {
                   return '<a class="btn btn-primary editarbtn" href=http://localhost/php/modificar_contenido.php?id_contenido=' + data + '>Editar</a><a data-toggle="modal" data-target="#basicModal"  class="btn btn-warning borrarbtn" href=http://localhost/php/borrar_contenido.php?id_contenido=' + data + '>Borrar</a>';
               }
           }]
       });
} );
```

---

> PHP File

```
   <?php
header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *');
/*
 * DataTables example server-side processing script.
 *
 * Please note that this script is intentionally extremely simply to show how
 * server-side processing can be implemented, and probably shouldn't be used as
 * the basis for a large complex system. It is suitable for simple use cases as
 * for learning.
 *
 * See http://datatables.net/usage/server-side for full details on the server-
 * side processing requirements of DataTables.
 *
 * @license MIT - http://datatables.net/license_mit
 */

/* * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * *
 * Easy set variables
 */

// DB table to use
$table = 'vpubli3';

// Table's primary key
$primaryKey = 'id_contenido';

// Array of database columns which should be read and sent back to DataTables.
// The `db` parameter represents the column name in the database, while the `dt`
// parameter represents the DataTables column identifier. In this case simple
// indexes
$columns = array(
    array( 'db' => 'id_contenido', 'dt' => 'IdContenido' ),
    array( 'db' => 'contenido',  'dt' => 'contenido' ),
    array( 'db' => 'fecha_inicio',   'dt' => 'fecha_inicio' ),
    array( 'db' => 'fecha_modificacion',     'dt' => 'fecha_modificacion' ),
    array( 'db' => 'descripcion',     'dt' => 'descripcion' ),
    array( 'db' => 'precio',     'dt' => 'precio' ),
    array( 'db' => 'cliente',     'dt' => 'cliente' ),
    array( 'db' => 'medio',     'dt' => 'medio' ),
    array( 'db' => 'editor',     'dt' => 'editor' )
);

// SQL server connection information
$sql_details = array(
    'user' => 'root',
    'pass' => 'root',
    'db'   => 'itm',
    'host' => 'localhost'
);


/* * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * *
 * If you just want to use the basic configuration for DataTables with PHP
 * server-side, there is no need to edit below this line.
 */

require( 'ssp.class.php' );

echo json_encode(
    SSP::simple( $_GET, $sql_details, $table, $primaryKey, $columns )
);
```

I dont have any errors now, but I had this error:

> cannot read property defaults of undefined line 20

Thank you so much

Comment: Did you really code your `main.js` with all those newlines in strange places? Or did your paste into SO do that?

Comment: Well edit the question and make it exactly as the real code is!

Comment: If you fetch your data via ajax, you need to implement all paging and sorting yourself server-side on the records returned. This is a avoid dumping 1000s of records every request. Currently you appear to be doing neither of those. What version of dataTables are you using (as the parameters changed name in V1.10)?

Comment: Im using dataTables v1.10.5 (the latest one)

Comment: For V 1.10+ the number of records to skip is in a request parameter called `start` and the number of records is in parameter `length`. Sorting is slightly more complicated (the first sort column is in `order[0][column]` and order ("asc" or "desc") in `order[0][dir]`)

Comment: im already changed the js file, but im using the parameters

Comment: You are not using them in the server code shown above.

Comment: just change the php code in the main post, can you check out if now it's fine?

Answer (score 0):

Can you use below function in your listing page where all records get loaded:

```
<link href="//cdn.datatables.net/1.10.0/css/jquery.dataTables.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<script src="http://legacy.datatables.net/release-datatables/media/js/jquery.js"></script>
<script src="//legacy.datatables.net/release-datatables/media/js/jquery.dataTables.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" language="javascript" class="init">
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#miTabla').dataTable( {
        "bProcessing": true,
        "bServerSide": true,
        "iDisplayLength":50,
        "sPaginationType": "full_numbers",
        "sAjaxSource": "YOURPHPPAGE.php"
    } );
} );
</script>
```

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/73773/discussion-on-answer-by-testing-datatables-jquery-default-pagination-ordering).

Answer (score 0):

Already solved the problem. I have a bad naming of a variable in my js code, thats the real problem. Corrected also in the answer